# Java Client/Server File transfer with Multithreading Problem

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I want to create simple download accelerator.

How it works

1. Server wait for incoming connection.
2. Client connect to server.
3. Then, server send file size to client and wait for download connection.
4. Client got file size, then create download thread and these thread are connect to server.
5. After server got connection from each thread, server will wait for start and end offset file from thread.
6. Each thread send start and end offset file to server.
7. After server got offsets, server will send the portion of file to thread.
8. Each thread will read and write to file. For example, buffer.p01, buffer.p02, buffer.p03
9. Client merge all file into one file order by sequence. ( **Not yet implemented** )

I think server side it works correctly but client side it has some problem.

The problem is if I set MAXTHREAD to 1, it works correctly. But if I set more than one, it stuck somewhere forever.

This is server side code..
http://pastebin.com/TEakGB0c

and this is client side code with multithreading
http://pastebin.com/wKhP7DxS

Thanks your.

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock issue. Without any code we can't really help?

Comment: I already post the code in the end of question. Could you see ?

Comment: Ah I see it now. Let me look.

Comment: @Atom, Having multiple connections helps if you want to increase your share of the bandwidth.  If all clients have the same number of connections, they will perform exactly the same.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand @_@. Could you show me some example please.

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense. Whether you have 1 or 10 connections, you are limited by the bandwidth.

Comment: @atom, Download accelerator work by getting a larger share of the limited bandwidth of the server. If a server has 100 connections you only the 1% of the bandwidth with one connection but 10% with 10 connections.  However, if all clients have 1 connection or all clients have 10 connections they all get the same share of bandwidth.  This technique only works by slowing down other clients by grabbing a higher share of the bandwidth, but in this case you would be only cheating yourself and you are unlikely to achieve anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty big obvious problem. ServerSocket's accept method returns a new socket every time. In your server code here

```
initSocket = servSock.accept();
```

initSocket is a class member field which means you will over write the old socket and never close it. You should start a new thread to handle this socket and from what I see it looks like you just keep reusing the same socket. That won't work. Look at tutorials on how to open sockets. Sorry I can't help more but there is a lot of things going on here that just won't work. Maybe you can start focusing on part of the code and we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it could be a small issue or it could be a big one, some example code would help us aid you, If you try to connect to a server 3 times using the same port you will get an error because you can only have 1 connection per port, the problem could be super simple or very complex, if you edit your post and add your code then we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please close your OutputStream os 

Sending u a snippet


public static boolean sendFile() {
        int start = Integer.parseInt(startAndEnd[0]) - 1;
        int end = Integer.parseInt(startAndEnd[1]) - 1;
        int size = (end - start) + 1;
        try {
            os = initSocket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(byteArr, start, size);
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("Send file to : " + initSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            disconnected();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```